# how to remove extra space from div using css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I am using a css grid in my demo application. I have a parent div that is having two child divs. In one of the child divs I gave a `height` of `270px`. I want to remove the extra space from the container.

Here is my [code](https://codepen.io/naveen-1234/pen/ExXNRbZ):

```css
.abc{
  display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,6.697%);
    grid-template-rows: 18px repeat(5, 1fe);
   border:1px solid green;
  height:320px
}
.one{
  grid-column: 4/span 6;
   grid-row: 2/span 5;
    border:1px solid;
  min-height:260px;
  height: 270px;  
}
.two {
  grid-row: 1/span 5;
   grid-column: 1/5;
    border:1px solid #ee0;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  
  <div class="one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium Lorem ipsum, 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    tooo
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: enter link description here]

I want to remove all the space below the **black border**. Should I reduce the container's height?

**Note**: I want the container height to depend on the div's height. Whether I give 270px or 290px. The container will be till there is no extra space.

[image]

Comment: Remove fixed height of 270px: https://codepen.io/Manoj6994/pen/wvegoQO

Comment: You may also want to change `1fe` to `1fr` for that statement to work.

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent div (.abc) height to **auto**.

```css
.abc{
  display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,6.697%);
    grid-template-rows: 18px repeat(5, 1fe);
   border:1px solid green;
  height:auto
}
.one{
  grid-column: 4/span 6;
   grid-row: 2/span 5;
    border:1px solid;
  min-height:260px;
  height: 270px;  
}
.two {
  grid-row: 1/span 5;
   grid-column: 1/5;
    border:1px solid #ee0;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  
  <div class="one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium Lorem ipsum, 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    tooo
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer .. this statement is not working now `grid-template-rows: 18px repeat(5, 1fe);
`

Comment: I want first row will be `18px`

Answer (score 0):

```css
.abc{
  display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12,6.697%);
    grid-template-rows: 18px auto;
   border:1px solid green;
}
.one{
  grid-column: 4/span 6;
   grid-row: 2/span 5;
    border:1px solid;
    min-height:260px;
    height: 270px;  
}
.two {
  grid-row: 1/span 5;
   grid-column: 1/5;
    border:1px solid #ee0;
}
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  
  <div class="one">
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates culpa iste facaudantium Lorem ipsum, 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    tooo
  </div>
</div>
```

I have removed the height of the parent div and changed grid-template-rows: 18px repeat(5, 1fe);  to **grid-template-rows: 18px auto;**

check if this will work for you
thanks